# Android - динамический контейнер для файлов

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Всем привет, мне нужно сделать что-то типа "контейнера" для файлов. Т.е. у меня есть кнопки - сделать фото/видео с камеры или прикрепить из галереи фото/видео. И всё, что прикрепляли - надо отобразить в неком контейнере, где ещё можно будет удалить определённый элемент (файл). Я пыталась сделать через RecyclerView - но что-то, как-то не пошло( Помогите пожалуйста меня направить в нужную сторону куда копать.

Comment: создайте список объектов с полями id и Bitmap. когда делаете фото или берете из галереи добавляете в этот список. отобразить в ресайклере тоже не проблема. при удалении айтема из ресайклера удаляете изображение из списка

Comment: я делал с помощью viewModel в ней у меня хранилась MutableLiveData<MutableList<LoadImage>>() и я на нее подписывался во вью